# Angular 5 app on ASP.Net web app routing issue

Tags: asp.net, angular, angular2-routing, iis-7.5

I am facing the following issue with an Angular 5 app deployed on IIS 7.5, inside a ASP.NET web app.

Let's assume the url of the Angular app is the following:

https://MyWebSite.com/MyApp/AngularApp/#

On UAT, with that path, the app automatically routed to the default route and displayed the default view of my angular app.

On Production, the site would not load, after hitting that path, I just got a "waiting for response..." message. No error, no 404, nothing, the web site just hangs on that stage eternally, not even hitting ctrl+F5 worked, I had to close the browser in order to get a response from the site again.

I was able to fix it on prod by changing the path to this:

https://MyWebSite.com/MyApp/AngularApp/index.html#main

This is my route code:

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {
   path: '',
   component: MainComponent
 },
 {
   path: 'main',
   component: MainComponent
 },
 {
   path: 'create',
   component: CreateWcComponent
 },
 { path: '**', redirectTo:'', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
     RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})
    ],
    exports: [
      RouterModule
    ]
...
```

Clearly for me this is an IIS configuration, but since I don't have direct access to the servers, I can't do the comparison. Please any advice on how this should be deployed.

Answer (score 0):

We include this IIS web.config file with all our Angular apps deployed onto IIS servers:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Just put it into the root of the application- in the angular application directory.